# Is it a good idea to make composition member objects public?

Tags: c++, interface, composition, public, class-hierarchy

I have a top-level class which instantiates sub modules using composition. The user knows that the top class will have these submodules. Is it a good idea to make the submodule objects public members so that the user can call their functions directly?

The alternative seems to be to wrap their function calls which protects the submodules from being made public, but doesn't have any encapsulation benefit since the user needs to specify the submodule anyway.

Here is a top-level class House with submodules kitchen and bathroom.

```
// Public member objects
class Kitchen {
public:
    void turn_on_tap();
    int compute_area();
};
class Bathroom {
public:
    void turn_on_tap();
    int compute_area();
};
class House {
public:
    Kitchen kitchen;
    Bathroom bathroom;
    int compute_area() { return kitchen.compute_area() + bathroom.compute_area(); }
};

//User code:
House house;
house.kitchen.turn_on_tap();
house.bathroom.turn_on_tap();
house.compute_area() // OK
house.bathroom.compute_area(); // may not want user to be able to do this

// Private member objects
class House {
    Kitchen kitchen;
    Bathroom bathroom;
public:
    void turn_on_kitchen_tap() { kitchen.turn_on_tap(); }
    void turn_on_bathroom_tap() { bathroom.turn_on_tap(); }
    int compute_area() { return kitchen.compute_area() + bathroom.compute_area(); }
};

//User code:
House house;
house.turn_on_kitchen_tap();
house.turn_on_bathroom_tap();
house.compute_area();
```

I prefer the syntax of the first but it means making the member objects public.

The second approach seems tedious because of the additional functions I have to write to wrap the underlying function calls. And I lose the nice dot hierarchical dereferencing because the user knows (and needs to know) about the underlying hierarchy.

EDIT: But if I make them public, I will expose other backend public functions in Kitchen and Bathroom that I don't necessarily want the user to be aware of. So then I might have to make those private and use "friend" which gets a little ugly.

Added compute_area() to above code.

Comment: If the sub classes do not have any members exposed to change their internal states except through public methods, then there should not be an issue with having an object in the containing class as public objects.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If a house is a simple aggregate, i.e:

1. A valid value of a `House` is any combination of valid values of `Kitchen`, and `Bathroom`. That is to say, there is no `House` specific invariant to keep.
2. The individual components handle their own invariants correctly by themselves, and by extension the container's given point No. 1.
3. The container's member functions are just tiny wrappers around each component, or even just return a reference to a component for modification.

Then yes, a simple `struct` (for the default public access) is indeed proper. "Encapsulating" here is just an exercise in verbosity. Sometimes the object you need *is* just a bunch of stuff glued together, with no further logic.

So whether or not it's a good a idea is something you will need to examine for your own application by yourself.